# Python Adding Invisible Characters When Using .append

Tags: list, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, append

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.showmeboone.com/sheriff/JailResidents/JailResidents.asp'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'collapse shadow BCSDTable'})

for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        text = cell.text
        print text
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    print list_of_cells
```

My python 2.7 code above

My output in Windows PowerShell below

```
PS D:\learnpython> python webscraper.py
[]
[]
[]
ACTON
CLINTON
WAYNE
M
W
35
STURGEON
MO
[u'ACTON', u'CLINTON', u'WAYNE', u'M', u'W', u'35', u'STURGEON', u'MO']
ALLEN
SHAUN
PHILLIP
M
W
28
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'ALLEN', u'SHAUN', u'PHILLIP', u'M', u'W', u'28', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
ANDERSON
ISAIAH
DWIGHT
M
B
19
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'ANDERSON', u'ISAIAH', u'DWIGHT', u'M', u'B', u'19', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
ANDREWS
SHEENA
MARIE
F
W
30
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'ANDREWS', u'SHEENA', u'MARIE', u'F', u'W', u'30', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
ASH
DONALD
DEAN
M
W
45
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'ASH', u'DONALD', u'DEAN', u'M', u'W', u'45', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
AVERY
DYLAN
KENT
M
W
19
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'AVERY', u'DYLAN', u'KENT', u'M', u'W', u'19', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BANKS
TIMOTHY
MAURICE
M
B
35
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BANKS', u'TIMOTHY', u'MAURICE', u'M', u'B', u'35', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BARNEY
MAXRILE
MARKEE
M
B
29
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BARNEY', u'MAXRILE', u'MARKEE', u'M', u'B', u'29', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BARR
DEBORAH
LYNN
F
W
51
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BARR', u'DEBORAH', u'LYNN', u'F', u'W', u'51', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BERGMAN
DARNELL
CORTEZ
M
B
35
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BERGMAN', u'DARNELL', u'CORTEZ', u'M', u'B', u'35', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BERRY
ISAIAH
LORENZ
M
B
18
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BERRY', u'ISAIAH', u'LORENZ', u'M', u'B', u'18', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BIRKEMEIER
ALEX
WILLIAM
M
W
25
FLORISSANT
MO
[u'BIRKEMEIER', u'ALEX', u'WILLIAM', u'M', u'W', u'25', u'FLORISSANT', u'MO']
BOTKINS
DAVID
EUGENE
M
W
32
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BOTKINS', u'DAVID', u'EUGENE', u'M', u'W', u'32', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BOWEN
DYLAN
MATTHEW EARL
M
W
24
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BOWEN', u'DYLAN', u'MATTHEW EARL', u'M', u'W', u'24', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BOWERS
LUCIUS
CLARENCE
M
B
39
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BOWERS', u'LUCIUS', u'CLARENCE', u'M', u'B', u'39', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BRANDES
NICHOLAS
SCOTT
M
W
32
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BRANDES', u'NICHOLAS', u'SCOTT', u'M', u'W', u'32', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BREWSTER
GREGORY
LASHUN
M
B
19
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BREWSTER', u'GREGORY', u'LASHUN', u'M', u'B', u'19', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BROADUS
WILLIAM
ANTHONY
M
B
29
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BROADUS', u'WILLIAM', u'ANTHONY', u'M', u'B', u'29', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BROWN
CHAKA
AISHA
F
B
37
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BROWN', u'CHAKA', u'AISHA', u'F', u'B', u'37', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BROWN
LARRY
JOHN
M
B
33
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BROWN', u'LARRY', u'JOHN', u'M', u'B', u'33', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BRYANT
JEREL
C.
M
B
36
MOBERLY
MO
[u'BRYANT', u'JEREL', u'C.', u'M', u'B', u'36', u'MOBERLY', u'MO']
BUNTYN
JAMMIE
LEE
M
B
25
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BUNTYN', u'JAMMIE', u'LEE', u'M', u'B', u'25', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BUTLER
DEANGELO
MONTREZ
M
B
25
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BUTLER', u'DEANGELO', u'MONTREZ', u'M', u'B', u'25', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BUTLER
FRANK
SHURELL
M
B
39
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BUTLER', u'FRANK', u'SHURELL', u'M', u'B', u'39', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BUTLER
JEMELL
DUPRUE
M
B
19
COLUMBIA

[u'BUTLER', u'JEMELL', u'DUPRUE', u'M', u'B', u'19', u'COLUMBIA', u'']
BUTLER
TERRY
LEON
M
B
53
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BUTLER', u'TERRY', u'LEON', u'M', u'B', u'53', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
BUTNER
TRESHAUN
DEVION
M
B
21
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'BUTNER', u'TRESHAUN', u'DEVION', u'M', u'B', u'21', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
CAMPBELL
WILLIAM
SHAKHEEM
M
B
17
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'CAMPBELL', u'WILLIAM', u'SHAKHEEM', u'M', u'B', u'17', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
CHAMBERS
AUSTIN
LEE
M
W
27
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'CHAMBERS', u'AUSTIN', u'LEE', u'M', u'W', u'27', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
CHICK
JAMIE
LEE
M
W
31
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'CHICK', u'JAMIE', u'LEE', u'M', u'W', u'31', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
CLARK
MARCUS
TERILE
M
B
32
KANSAS CITY
MO
[u'CLARK', u'MARCUS', u'TERILE', u'M', u'B', u'32', u'KANSAS CITY', u'MO']
CLARO-RIVERA
JONI
JAVIER
M
H
20
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'CLARO-RIVERA', u'JONI', u'JAVIER', u'M', u'H', u'20', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
COCKRELL
WILLIAM
ELMER
M
W
50
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'COCKRELL', u'WILLIAM', u'ELMER', u'M', u'W', u'50', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
COFIELD
CHRISTOPHER
NEAL
M
B
43
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'COFIELD', u'CHRISTOPHER', u'NEAL', u'M', u'B', u'43', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
COMMANDER
JAVANTE
BRUCE
M
B
20
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'COMMANDER', u'JAVANTE', u'BRUCE', u'M', u'B', u'20', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
COOPER
TRE
LAMONT
M
B
23
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'COOPER', u'TRE', u'LAMONT', u'M', u'B', u'23', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
COOPER
WILLIAM
DEONTE
M
B
35
MACON
MO
[u'COOPER', u'WILLIAM', u'DEONTE', u'M', u'B', u'35', u'MACON', u'MO']
COZEAN
KIRSTIE
ANN
F
W
24
JOPLIN
MO
[u'COZEAN', u'KIRSTIE', u'ANN', u'F', u'W', u'24', u'JOPLIN', u'MO']
CRAIG
BREAH
NICHOLE
F
B
23
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'CRAIG', u'BREAH', u'NICHOLE', u'F', u'B', u'23', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
CROSS
TAMARA
SHAWNTISE
F
B
35
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'CROSS', u'TAMARA', u'SHAWNTISE', u'F', u'B', u'35', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
CROWLEY
MIKEL
DERRICE
M
B
20
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'CROWLEY', u'MIKEL', u'DERRICE', u'M', u'B', u'20', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
CUNNINGHAM
MEGAN
NICOLE
F
W
21
HALLSVILLE
MO
[u'CUNNINGHAM', u'MEGAN', u'NICOLE', u'F', u'W', u'21', u'HALLSVILLE', u'MO']
CUNNINGHAM
MYLONYO
TRAMIRE
M
B
23
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'CUNNINGHAM', u'MYLONYO', u'TRAMIRE', u'M', u'B', u'23', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO'
DALTON
RAYMOND
RUSH
M
W
20
MILLERSBURG
MO
[u'DALTON', u'RAYMOND', u'RUSH', u'M', u'W', u'20', u'MILLERSBURG', u'MO']
DAVID
BRADLY
GENE
M
W
48
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'DAVID', u'BRADLY', u'GENE', u'M', u'W', u'48', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
DAVIS
TONY
LA'CONDA
M
B
50
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'DAVIS', u'TONY', u"LA'CONDA", u'M', u'B', u'50', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
DENNY
DEANDRE
LAVELLE
M
B
19
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'DENNY', u'DEANDRE', u'LAVELLE', u'M', u'B', u'19', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
DICKERSON
CORNELIUS
ODELL
M
B
42
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'DICKERSON', u'CORNELIUS', u'ODELL', u'M', u'B', u'42', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
DONIGIAN
CHARLES
ROSS
M
W
20
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'DONIGIAN', u'CHARLES', u'ROSS', u'M', u'W', u'20', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
DUDLEY
FLOYD
WILLIAM
M
B
28
COLUMBIA
MO
[u'DUDLEY', u'FLOYD', u'WILLIAM', u'M', u'B', u'28', u'COLUMBIA', u'MO']
PS D:\learnpython>
```

I am trying to scrape data from a website using BeautifulSoup in Python 2.7. I'm able to pull out the data from each of the cells and I can print them all fine and they appear as is without a 'u' in front of them. When I try to put them together into lists with the .append function a 'u' is added before each word. I'm not sure where this 'u' is coming from because I don't see it when each word is printed individually and I don't know how to get rid of it. Is it coming from the .append function? I can't figure this out. Also, I'm unsure of where the 3 empty brackets are coming from at the top of the output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Link to what I see when I look at the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oosu5.png)

[Link to the web scraping tutorial I am following along with](https://first-web-scraper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#act-3-web-scraping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Empty list

The brackets `[]` represent an empty list, which you print out in each iteration of the `<tr>` for loop.
You could check the length of the list before printing it to stdout.

```py2
    if len(list_off_cells) > 0:
        print list_of_cells
```

The document might have tr tags without any td tags inside of them.
This would be the case for `<th>` tags inside the `<tr>` tag.

### The "hidden" character

When you print out the list of cells the `u` before the string indicates that this is a unicode string.

The BeautifulSoup module converts the HTML document to unicode first. So when you access a specific element's text value yields you an unicode value.

The following short example should let you see that:

```py2
# This is a list of unicode strings
l = [u"cell1", u"cell2"]
# print the list
print l
# Print the type of the first element of the list
print type(l[0])
```

the output of the above script:

```
[u'cell1', u'cell2']
<type 'unicode'>
```

See [Unicode HowTo](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code)